# Required Field Validator is Validate call needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have inherited some old, bad code that I am trying to convert from VB to C# and bring up to snuff (or at least make not quite so laughable).

I have found code like this all over the place in it:

```
rfvReasons.Validate();

if rfvReasons.isValid)
{
    // do something
}
```

Are these Validate calls needed every time you want to use an isValid?  Doesn't the onChange event of the objects cause the validator to update?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not typically need to call `.Validate();` on the validator before checking the `isValid` property.  The validation is performed when they page posts back to the server, so `isValid` should be up to date when you're running your server side code.

See the [`BaseValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.aspx) class (from which the `RequiredFieldValidator` is derived):

> ASP.NET provides many controls that have the ability to post back to
>   the server. When one of these controls has its CausesValidation
>   property set to true, validation is performed when the control posts
>   back to the server.

Comment: @jadarnal27: thanks, that's what I thought, but there were so many calls of Validate() in the code that it had me second guessing.

Comment: @Limey A completely understandable response =)  It seems like the coder that wrote that was just being extra-careful, or didn't really understand how the validation control worked.

Comment: well, considering that were named requiredFieldValidator1 thru 15, I'm guessing the second.  :)